# Gin v1.9.1 with go1.21.2 on Centos8 and Debian11 (Google Cloud VM instance) - Server-side push issue

Tags: google-chrome, go, google-cloud-platform, centos8, go-gin

I am facing an issue with `gin` on `Centos8` and on `Debian11 (Google Cloud VM instance)`. Not sure whether it is gin issue or go issue or os issue or network issue ...

This works fine, I get `HTTP/2` in the output message for `curl -I ...` ...

```
[GIN] 2023/10/08 - 05:49:29 | 404 |     184.381µs |     98.33.79.20 | HEAD     "/api/associations/get"
```

However, this fails for `curl ...` (that is, without the `-I` option) ...

```
Failed to push: feature not supported
[GIN] 2023/10/08 - 05:49:55 | 200 |      119.21µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Here's server-side log for request from curl ...

```
 . Request.Header: map[Accept:[*/*] User-Agent:[curl/8.2.1]]
 . Failed to push: feature not supported
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:29:34 | 200 |     106.951µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
```

Here's server-side log for request from chrome ...

```
 . Request.Header: map[Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.9] Cache-Control:[max-age=0] Sec-Ch-Ua:["Google Chrome";v="117", "Not;A=Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="117"] Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile:[?0] Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform:["macOS"] Sec-Fetch-Dest:[document] Sec-Fetch-Mode:[navigate] Sec-Fetch-Site:[none] Sec-Fetch-User:[?1] Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36]]
 . Failed to push: feature not supported
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:28:43 | 200 |     165.912µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
```

`NOTE`: Works with Firefox and httpie and postman ...

```
 . Request.Header: map[Accept:[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Accept-Language:[en-US,en;q=0.5] Dnt:[1] Sec-Fetch-Dest:[document] Sec-Fetch-Mode:[navigate] Sec-Fetch-Site:[cross-site] Sec-Gpc:[1] Te:[trailers] Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:[1] User-Agent:[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/118.0]]
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:28:28 | 200 |     420.227µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:28:28 | 200 |   10.307439ms |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/assets/app.js"
```

```
 . Request.Header: map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate] Connection:[keep-alive] User-Agent:[HTTPie/3.0.2]]
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:38:18 | 200 |      92.935µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
```

```
 . Request.Header: map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip, deflate, br] Connection:[keep-alive] Postman-Token:[b77c5987-8228-4584-a486-9a0f3f748f77] User-Agent:[PostmanRuntime/7.32.3]]
[GIN] 2023/10/09 - 00:55:08 | 200 |     189.142µs |     98.33.79.20 | GET      "/api/associations/get"
```

I am using `go1.21.2` and `gin v1.9.1`

Thanks

Comment: In summary - Works from Firefox, Postman, HTTPie, Fails from Chrome, Curl

Comment: My next debugging step would be to capture traffic with tcpdump and compare successful and unsuccessful attempts.